# correct usage of 'which'

Tags: grammaticality, relative-clauses

If I say this sentence, would it be meaningful?

> Similarly, trees can be described by neighborhood relations *which* we
>   can see how trees exist with other objects in reality

Actually what I want to say is: trees can be described using neighborhood relations that they make with other objects in their vicinity.

Comment: Trees can be described on the basis of their *interdependence with other objects in the vicinity?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not grammatical. The relative clause isn't formed right.

What you appear to mean is something like the grammatical relative clause

- ... *neighborhood relations **which allow us to see how trees ...***

  > (parenthetically, this relative clause could be pronounced as **either** [restrictive **or** non-restrictive](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/xmasthat.html); insert a comma before *which* in writing it, if it's intended to be non-restrictive)

In this relative clause, *which* is coreferential to *relations*, **and** *which* is also the subject of *allow* in the relative clause; *us*, on the other hand, is the subject of the infinitive *to see* in the complement clause that is the direct object of *allow*. This sorts out the relations in logical form.

The relative clause in your sentence, however, collapses the two concepts of allowing and perceiving into one clause with a complex verb phrase *can see how trees ...*

- ... *neighborhood relations **which we can see how trees ...***

with *we* as the subject of the verb phrase. But what's *which* doing?

- It can't be the subject of *can see* -- that's *we*.
- It can't be the object of *can see* -- that's the embedded question clause *how trees ...*

Nothing is left for *which* to refer to. Hence it's not a [relative clause](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/relatives.pdf), since there has to be some noun phrase coreferential to the antecedent in a relative clause. So it's ungrammatical.

Answer (score 4):

Not really.  For your example, I would not use 'which' at all.  An alternative might be this:

```
Similarly, trees can be described by comparison with nearby objects.
```

although it is difficult to know without the context.